# Node js POST method with no response, but works fine at POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, client-server

I have a node aplication at localhost:3000 with this CORS config:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  app.use(cors());

  next();
});
```

And here i have my post method:

```
router.post('/saveragnarokuser',function(req,res,next){

    console.log('######################### Iniciando saveragnarokuser.');

    UserRagnarokController.addUser(req.body,function(err,count){
        if(err){
            console.log('entrei aqui error: ' + err);
            res.json(err);
        }
        else{

            console.log('entrei aqui ok');

            var userObj = {
                response: "OK"
             };

            res.json(userObj);
        }
    });
});
```

when im trying to access this route by html/javascript the server-side console says:

```
OPTIONS /user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/ 200 0.565 ms - 4
######################### Iniciando saveragnarokuser.
myReqbody: {"userid":"bruna","userpass":"teste","email":"acosta.aluiz@gmail.com","sex":"M"}
POST /user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/ - - ms - -
entrei aqui ok
```

That is my javaScript (Client-side) method with XMLHttpRequest:

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();

function handler() {
    if(invocation.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && invocation.status === 200) {
        alert('entrei aqui');
        console.log(invocation.responseText);
    } else 
        alert('nao foi hj');
}

function saveUser() {   
    alert('face');
    var eml = document.getElementById('emailInputRegister');
    var user = document.getElementById('userInputText');
    var sx = document.getElementById("sexInputSelected");
    var selectedSex = sx.options[sx.selectedIndex].value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById("passwordInputRegister");

    var uri = 'http://localhost:3000/user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/';
    var body = {
        'userid': user.value,
        'userpass': pwd.value,
        'email': eml.value,
        'sex': selectedSex
    };

    invocation.open('POST', uri, true);

    invocation.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    invocation.onreadystatechange = this.handler;
    invocation.send(JSON.stringify(body));
}
}
```

When i connect to this route with POSTMAN everything works fine. I noticed that the request by POSTMAN does not have the connection OPTIONS log

```
######################### Iniciando saveragnarokuser.
myReqbody: {"userid":"1234658","userpass":"teste","email":"acosta.aluiz@gmail.com","sex":"M"}
entrei aqui ok
POST /user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/ 200 10089.318 ms - 17
```

[image: POSTMAN Result]

Comment: The `POST /user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/ 400 26.881 ms - 936` response shown indicates that the HTTP status code of the response to the POST request is a 400 Bad Request error. That has nothing to do with CORS but instead indicates the server is saying the request was not formatted in the way the server expects. Check your server logs on the server for that `/user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/` endpoint, and look for error messages that are logged there which give more-specific information about what’s wrong with the request.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

```
invocation.send(body);
```

Try with below

```
invocation.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

Your code was trying to send the request with `body.toString()` per my understanding.

Comment: Something change with body string object. Now service are working, the data are saved at mySQL, but the response continue the same at the browser. At the log server response change to OPTIONS /user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/ 200 0.565 ms - 4
######################### Iniciando saveragnarokuser.
myReqbody: {"userid":"bruna","userpass":"teste","email":"acosta.aluiz@gmail.com","sex":"M"}
POST /user-ragnarok-controller/saveragnarokuser/ - - ms - -. POST is out of status with -- in -- ms